# Calculate a forward rate using measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of the following format:

[image]

I need to calculate a "Forward Rate" measure for each row, which = Discount Factor Current Month / Discount Factor Proceeding Month - 1.

I have tried the following measure but it does not work:

```
Forward Rate = SUMX(facYieldCurves, 
IFERROR( 
    DIVIDE(LOOKUPVALUE(facYieldCurves[Discount Factor], facYieldCurves[Month] , [Month] - 1) , [Discount Factor]),0))
```

Comment: Please don't paste data as an image. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

```
Measure = 
IF(HASONEVALUE('Table'[Month]), 
    DIVIDE(
        MAX('Table'[Discount Factor]),
        CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Discount Factor]), REMOVEFILTERS(), VALUES('Table'[Curve]), 'Table'[Month]=MAX('Table'[Month])-1),
        0
    )
)
```